# Why am I getting "function func has internal linkage but is not defined" on mac

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

In the `main.cpp` I have

```
#include "helper.h"
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //switch between list and vector
    list<int> a = {0, 1};
    list<char> b = {'a', 'b'};

    func(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

My `helper.h` looks like

```
template <class C1, class C2>
void func(C1 &a, C2 &b)
```

and my `helper.cpp` looks like

```
#include <list>
#include "helper.h"

template <class C1, class C2>
void func (C1 &a, C2 &b)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Then building it in Terminal on Mac with `g++ main.cpp mysort.cpp -o sorting -std=c++11` generates the error `"function func has internal linkage but is not defined"` and `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void func<std::__1::list<char, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >, main::$_0>(std::__1::list<char, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::list<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, main::$_0)", referenced from:
      _main in main-202a16.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: The definition of the template function needs to be visible in `main.cpp`. The typical way to do that is to define the template function in the header file, at the point of declaration.

Comment: I read the "Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?" thread and your comment @CodyGray, but I don't really get what I need to do now?!

Comment: Move the definition of the `func` function into the header file!